# Can a coordinating conjunction connect units with different grammar ranks?

Tags: conjunctions

Can a coordinating conjunction connect units with different grammar ranks (like a phrase and a clause together)?

**Example 1:**

> I drank Starbucks coffee **last month** and **when my mom came to visit me last week**.

**Example 2:**

> I drank Starbucks coffee **because of the aromatic coffee beans** and **because I liked the ambiance there**.

Comment: They are not in different rank, I guess. They are different grammatical structures but they have same functions. A coordinator coordinates the units with the same function.

Comment: In this case, there is no grammatical reason why they should not. The first sounds a little awkward (to me) but that's a stylistic issue, not a grammatical issue.

Comment: (1) would be more natural with _and again_ (assuming the speaker didn't visit Starbucks between last month and Mom's visit).

Comment: But both your examples have ***the same*** "syntactic category" before and after the "coordinating conjunction" ***and***. It would be different if you'd written *I drank Starbucks coffee because of the aromatic coffee beans **and** when my mom came to visit me last week*, because in that example the clauses before and after the conjunction are ***not*** "compatible", so there's no justification for trying to "coordinate" them into a single utterance. I think that might be a form of "**zeugma**".